# unable to upload file from the page via rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I've got `Spring Boot` application that I initialize like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.high.level.package" })
@EnableEmailTools
@EnableAsync
public class BookViewApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookViewApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`ComponentScan` is set to high level package so it is able to find all components (because services, repositories etc. works)

I've got a config for displaying `html` page

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/books-home").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

`index.html` displayed fine.

I've got `ServletInitializer` that looks like this

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BookViewApplication.class);
    }

}
```

I've got `spring-data-rest` resource that works fine

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface IBooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

I've got a `controller` for rest

```
@RestController("/books-rest")
public class BooksWebController {

    @Autowired
    private IBooksFileRepository fileRepository;

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                fileRepository.writeFile(file.getName(), file.getBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/books-home";
    }

}
```

I can access

```
localhost:8080/books
localhost:8080/books-home
```

But when I try to access with `POST` request

```
localhost:8080/books-rest
```

using this form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/books-rest/upload">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File to upload:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I get `404 not found`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
Change `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody`.